# Grounding problem is coming between boost converter and MOSFET driver

Tags: dc-dc-converter, grounding, boost, mosfet-driver

I am designing a boost converter which is rated on 100 watts, 12 volt to 24 volt, switching frequency is 20 kHz, in open-loop conditions.
When I give the input power supply to the circuit as 12 volt, my driver (HCPL 4506 MOSFET driver) will take VCC as 24 volt due to my microcontroller can generate a 3.3-volt output PWM 20 kHz switching frequency so when low-level amplitude generated by a microcontroller will be given to the low side of MOSFET driver to get a large amplitude of voltage from the high side of the driver.
The voltage should be large enough which can turn on the gate terminal of MOSFET. The threshold voltage of my MOSFET is 15 volt for turning on the gate.

So suppose if I provide VCC as 12 volt in the driver, so they will give low amplitude voltage as volts approx, it is not enough to turn on the gate of the MOSFET.
So when we are working in the circuit we checked we need to provide 24 volt to the driver circuit (VCC) then it can generate 15 volt approx, it is enough to turn on the gate of MOSFET.

Now when I have built this circuit with proper orientation in an open loop, the problem is coming.
I have 24 volt DC supply (SMPS) for the input power supply where I am using a voltage regulator 7812 IC which will convert 24 to 12 volt for the boost converter (power circuit) and 24 volts directly given to the driver VCC.
When I powered on the circuit, the output voltage of the boost converter is coming 4 volt, I should come 24 volt.
I checked this circuit, all the things are good. I think I am getting a grounding problem.
Anyone can help me with this?[image]

please note in the circuit diagram output is 24 volts dc

one more thing I want to add the purpose of doing this circuit is
actually, I am going to build a solar inverter which is around 1 KW rated,
and role of the boost converter is to step up the voltage from 150volts receives through solar panels and boost up to 400 volts for the DC link capacitor.
Maybe when anyone reads the above problem anyone can ask me why I am doing this?
Doing this operation only checking the behavior of the control circuit, power circuit, calculations at a low power level before going into High-level power circuit.

Comment: Why haven't you posted a schematic?

Comment: okay I will do it now.

Comment: @Andyaka sir please the schematic.